# How does the std namespace to increase his content?

Tags: c++, namespaces

Im new in C++, coming from java, javascript and similar languages.

I understand that std is a namespace that includes very much funcionality, constants, functions, etc. But how increment his content by add header files via `#include`, for example:

```cpp
// main.cpp

int main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In this case, when I try to compile, gives an error that says:

> 'cout' is not a member of 'std'
> happends too with `std::endl` too.

Arrived here: yes I know that I must include the iostream header.

In conclusion I ask, how a namespace can increase his content and if this functionality can be replicated in another namespace

EDIT:
To clearify my problem will update the previous example:
if I add at the top of the file `#include <iostream>` the compilation error is fixed:

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "test" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What I mean to 'increase the content' is, In the first example (where iostream is not included via `#include`) `cout` and `endl` was not defined, because iostream was not included. But at the moment where I included iostream using `#include <iostream>`, `cout` and `endl` was able to use because iostream was included.

Comment: You "add" to a namespace by simply declaring or defining structures, classes, functions, variables, etc. inside a namespace.

Comment: The header file simply contains `namespace std { ... }` with the stuff inside the braces.

Comment: As a example, in one header file you can have `namespace foo { void function1(); }`, and in another header file you can have `namespace foo { int function2(int); }`. If you include both header files, you can call both `foo::function1` and `foo::function2`.

Comment: Note that we can't(generally) add things into namespace `std`

Comment: Ok, I understand now, I feel so dumb now xd. Its a "redefinition" quote unquote. Of the same namespace with differents contents in every "redefinition".

Comment: Note that there's no way to forbid declaring a namespace, not even `std`.  You can add symbols to *any* namespace. The C++ specification explicitly say that with a few exceptions (for specializations of `std::hash` for example) any addition to the `std` namespace leads to undefined behavior. But there's no explicit syntactic mechanisms to forbid it. Which sometimes make it unwanted. For those cases a class with `static` functions can be used instead.